# Angular ng-grid: How to access json properties named with incrementing integers?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ng-grid

So I'm trying to populate an ng-grid instance with json via a rest API. I've tested this already and it works in the setup, so I know it's not a configuration issue. When it worked the API was returning a json object with a top level "users": object containing an array I think. I was able to get the values in the user object really easily as it was named.

Now the API has changed, and it's returning the users each in an object named with an incrementing integer. I'm not sure how to access these properties. 
Here's a stripped down model of the json.

```
{
    "1": {
        "id":"1",
        "first_name":"Bob",
        "last_name":"Jones",
        "email":"bob@jones.com",
        "status":"1"
    },
    "2": {
        "id":"2",
        "first_name":"Mike",
        "last_name":"Jones",
        "email":"mike@jones.com",
        "status":"1"
    },
    "3": {
        "id":"3",
        "first_name":"John",
        "last_name":"Jones",
        "email":"john@jones.com",
        "status":"0"
    }
}
```

In my controller I'm setting up the grid like this :

```
$scope.usersList = usersFactory.list.query()
    .then(function (data){
      return data;
    }, function (error){
      console.log('ruh roh');
    });
```

then

```
$scope.userListGrid = { 
    data: 'usersList',
    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
      {field:'first_name', displayName:'First name'}, 
      {field:'last_name', displayName:'Last name'},
      {field:'email', displayName:'Email'}, 
      {field:'status', displayName:'Status'}
    ]};
```

So my question is, how can I access the first children in the json response without know their exact names? Do I need to loop over them all and put them into an array or something like that first?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: please, post old json too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't think `ng-grid` can handle this directly; you should transform your data into an array in the success callback function, or in the `transformResponse` callback of the resource's `query()` method.

Comment: ah ok I was thinking maybe I'd have to do that. Thanks!

Comment: Luckily I have good contact with the backend dev and he's going to reformat the JSON to use an array instead of indexed entries. :D Cheating!